# Need help figuring out a regular expression for these strings

Tags: regex, perl

I'm just learning regex and I've been trying to figure out a pattern which only matches the following strings:

```
-a
-A
--add
--Add
a
A
add
Add
```

I'm using this in Perl if it matters. If you answer, could you explain your regex so I can try and learn what I've been doing wrong?

Comment: Check out RegExr, it's a great tool for testing regexes: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Another resource to check out is the perl module Regexp::Assemble

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^(-?[aA]|(--)?[aA]dd)$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `-?[aA]`:

  - `-?` matches `-` or nothing
  - `[aA]` matches `a` or `A`
- `(--)?[aA]dd`:

  - `(--)?` matches `--` or nothing
  - `[aA]` matches `a` or `A`
  - `dd` matches `dd`
- `(x|y)` matches `x` or `y`
- `$` matches the end of the string

You should invest some time carefully reading http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html. I still need a reference handy when I write regular expressions.

Comment: Works perfectly, and thanks to your explanation I fully understand regex and I'm making some more for my application. Many thanks!